# Техника pimpl c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Что такое техника `pimpl` и когда нужно её использовать?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213259/whats-is-the-point-of-pimpl-pattern-while-we-can-use-interface-for-the-same-pur

Comment: [HABR: Идиомы Pimpl и Fast Pimpl – указатель на реализацию](https://habr.com/post/111602/)

Comment: еще можете почитать про реализацию d-pointer и pimpl в qt https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer

Comment: pimpl на примере Qt https://habr.com/post/76248/

Answer (score 7):

Идиома pimpl (pointer to implementation - указатель на реализацию) полезна в тех случаях, когда нам нужно что-то скрыть. Она обеспечивает еще более глубокий вид инкапсуляции, которая маскирует не просто реализацию, а также все ее зависимости.

Например, мы создаем библиотеку, которая сама зависит от сторонних библиотек. При этом мы собираемся передать нашу библиотеку кому-то другому без исходников. Чтобы не тянуть зависимости в виде заголовочных файлов (как минимум) и не раскрыть слишком много деталей реализации в интерфейсе класса (как максимум), мы можем воспользоваться идиомой pimpl.

#### Пример

```
// widget.h (interface)
class widget {
    // public members
private:
    struct impl;  // forward declaration of the implementation class
    // One implementation example: see below for other design options and trade-offs
    std::experimental::propagate_const< // const-forwarding pointer wrapper
        std::unique_ptr<                // unique-ownership opaque pointer
            impl>> pImpl;               // to the forward-declared implementation class
};

// widget.cpp (implementation)
struct widget::impl {
   // implementation details
};
```

Этот метод используется для создания интерфейсов библиотеки C ++ со стабильным ABI и сокращения зависимостей во времени компиляции.

Поскольку частные члены данных класса участвуют в представлении объекта, влияя на размер и макет, а также потому, что частные функции-члены класса участвуют в разрешении перегрузки (что происходит до проверки доступа к членству), любое изменение этих деталей реализации требует перекомпиляции всех пользователей класса.

pImpl нарушает эту зависимость от компиляции; изменения в реализации не вызывают перекомпиляции. Следовательно, если библиотека использует pImpl в своем ABI, более новые версии библиотеки могут изменить реализацию, оставаясь ABI-совместимой со старыми версиями.

#### Полезные ссылки

- [Статья на хабре](https://habr.com/post/111602/)
- [Статья с evileg](https://evileg.com/ru/post/322/)
- [Вопрос с английского stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice)